# Problems with setting up bonding on Netplan (Ubuntu server 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, yaml

I have a dual port network card that I want to bond both ports and balance the traffic between ports.  I want 1 static IP address.  I used to ubuntu 16.04 and this worked fine.  Im now trying to set up the same thing in netplan and am struggling.  My config is below...

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  enp1s0f0:
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
  enp1s0f1:
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
 bonds:
   bond0:
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
   interfaces: 
     - enp1s0f0
     - enp1s0f1
   addresses: [192.168.3.250/24]
   gateway4: 192.168.3.1
   parameters:
     mode: 802.3ad
   nameservers:
     addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033531/how-can-i-create-a-bond-interface-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax.

```
$ sudo netplan --debug apply
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  enp1s0f0:
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
  enp1s0f1:
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
 bonds:
  bond0:
   dhcp4: false
   dhcp6: false
   interfaces:
     - enp1s0f0
     - enp1s0f1
   addresses: [192.168.3.250/24]
   gateway4: 192.168.3.1
   parameters:
     mode: 802.3ad
   nameservers:
     addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```